# Does the python format specifier allow using a comma for a decimal point?

Tags: python, localization, string-formatting

Technically I'm using javascript but the [d3.format](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Formatting#wiki-d3_format) function supports python [format specifier language](http://docs.python.org/release/3.1.3/library/string.html#formatspec).

I am building something to be used in Germany where they would like numbers to be formatted with a comma for decimal symbol like so: `14,5`. Is it possible to create a specifier that would format it like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python, I think this is out of scope for the python format specifier language because it is covered by the [locale module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/locale.html#locale.localeconv).

The [python format](http://docs.python.org/release/3.1.3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language) does have a `n` presentation type that is specifically locale aware, but [d3.format](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Formatting#wiki-d3_format) maps `n` to `,g`.